# Special character in \url

Tags: urls, characters

I am stuck with a problem of a url to some website I try to put a link to.

The URL is: [http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prawo_Lewisa-Mogridge’a](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prawo_Lewisa-Mogridge%E2%80%99a)
and Latex have an issue with the ’ symbol. 
I put it the very easy way:

```
\url{http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prawo_Lewisa-Mogridge’a}
```

but the result is quite different:

```
http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prawo_Lewisa-Mogridge%5CT1%5Ctextquoteright_a
```

I obviously use UTF8 but the URL is Polish. Any idea what could be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to wikipedia and copy its URL as such; then add `\` before each `%`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{http://www.wikiwand.com/pl/Prawo_Lewisa-Mogridge\%E2\%80\%99a}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 1**

Instead of \url, you can use \href, in case you want the hyperlink:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \href{http://www.wikiwand.com/pl/Prawo_Lewisa-Mogridge\%E2\%80\%99a}
    {http://wikiwand.com/pl/Prawo\_Lewisa-Mogridge\textquoteright{}a}
\end{document}
```

[image: URL with textquoteright]

**EDIT 2**

On the other hand, according to Wikipedia, this is the right way to cite:

//pl.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Prawo_Lewisa-Mogridge%E2%80%99a&oldid=39769503

Check the [link](http://pl.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Specjalna:Cytuj&page=Prawo_Lewisa-Mogridge%E2%80%99a&id=39769503)

Comment: No need of adding `\ ` when you use `\url` from `url` package (which is loaded by `hyperref`).

Comment: Oh well... the link is working, but it is displayed like this: http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prawo_Lewisa-Mogridge%E2%80%99a

Comment: @Atais. This is the right way to type it, because not every font may have the character

Comment: @HarishKumar. According to the url manual (p.1), «the \url argument cannot contain any “%”, “#”, or “^^”, or end with “\”.»

Answer (score 0):

In case of one # inside \url in bib, I had to replicate it four times like this:

```
@Misc{hausdorff,
  author       = {plastimatch},
  howpublished = {\url{http://plastimatch.org/doxygen/classHausdorff__distance.html####details}},
```

I was in Overleaf with:

```
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
```

Comment: With `biblatex` (and all BIbTeX styles that support it) it is preferable to use the dedicated `url` field and not the general-purpose `howpublished`. You can (and should) input URLs in the `url` field without any escaping: `url = {http://plastimatch.org/doxygen/classHausdorff__distance.html#details},` The URL will automatically be formatted with the `\url` macro: It need not and should not be used in the `url` field.

Comment: @moewe: Why it's preferable to use `url` over `general-purpose`? In case I need to use `general-purpose`, how can we fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @Catbuilts Using the `url` field gives your bibliography style more control over the formatting of the URL and avoids unnecessary hard-coding of markup in the `.bib` file. There are some older `.bst` styles that don't support a `url` field; in that case sticking with `howpublished` might be easiest. But in the use cases stipulated in the answer (`\usepackage{biblatex}`) almost all styles support the `url` field, so there is no need to go for `howpublished`.